# Xamarin Forms Custom Behavior Validation with List<Items>

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I am trying to replicate this very informative [tutorial](http://xamgirl.com/custom-entry-validation-in-xamarin-forms/) to implement validation with Xamarin Forms behaviours for a Xamarin Forms application. The tutorial is based on a single User model scenario, whereas my case is based on a List of Items. I believe my validation logic is working correctly, however, the view is not changing to indicate validation errors: the tutorial aims to add a red border and inline validation error messages to the fields which are not successfully validated.

In the tutorial the validation is being done in a command declared within the constructor and the error messages are simply set within the model's properties. This updates the XAML view, to my understanding due to the data binding implemented within the view. In my case, I am attempting the same thing, validating in the save command, and updating the values in the List. I also have visibility that the actual "erroneous" object is edited within the list, but the ExtendedEntry in the view does not update with red borders and an error message as expected. I also tried to clear the ObservableCollection and re build it by adding one item at a time. My question is, why would my solution not work with a list of items? Does the logic not stand in this case?

Adding some snippets for reference below:

The tutorial was used to extend on the Entry component and create an ExtendedEntry component which accepts more properties, such as a border and inline validation messages. For this reason, custom renderers were implemented per platform. An entry behaviour was also created to handle the behavioural changes of the form. I am not including these as I am assuming copying and paste them from the link should not have ruined the code.

The model includes 2 validation fields, 1 to define whether the red border appears, the other to define the validation message.

```
public class MetaData: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }     
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public bool Mandatory { get; set; }

    public bool IsNotValid { get; set; }
    public string NotValidMessageError { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

The ViewModel constructor, which also contains the OnValidationCommand. I am not sure whether the global List is being bound to the view. So I tried updating both the List and the Observable collection one by one.

```
public ObservableCollection<MetaData> Items { get; set; }
public List<MetaData> MetadataList { get; set; }
public ICommand OnValidationCommand { get; set; }

 public MetadataPreviewViewModel(List<MetaData> md)
    {
        MetadataList = md;

        OnValidationCommand = new Command((obj) =>
        {
            Items.Clear();

            bool errorValidation = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < MetadataList.Count; i++)
            {
                var item = MetadataList[i];

                var tempItem = Validate(item);

                MetadataList[i] = tempItem;

                Items.Add(tempItem);
            }



        });

        Title = "Metadata";
        Items = new ObservableCollection<MetaData>();
        LoadItemsCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadItemsCommand());
    }

  public MetaData Validate(MetaData item)
    {
        int intType = Convert.ToInt16(item.Type);

        switch (intType)
        {
            case (int)DefaultValueType.Custom_Date:
                // need to validate date
                item.IsNotValid = false;
                break;
            default: {
                    if (item.Mandatory) 
                    {
                        if (item.Value != null && item.Value != "")
                            item.IsNotValid = false;
                        else
                        {
                            item.IsNotValid = true;
                            item.NotValidMessageError = item.Name + " is required.";
                        }

                    }
                    break;
                }
        }

        return item;
    }
```

In the XAML I am using various DataTemplates and a DataTemplateSelector to include different layouts with different components in the XAML. I have only tried to implement validation in this template yet. Below is the DataTemplate declaration in the ResourceDictionary and the ContentPage.Content section with the ListView declaration, also specifying a template selector. Note, that the template selector is working correctly and the right templates are being displayed for the different scenarios.

```
 <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="textTemplate">
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid Padding="8">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.4*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.6*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Column="0"  Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                    <local1:ExtendedEntry Grid.Column="1" ErrorText="{Binding NotValidMessageError, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                 BorderErrorColor="Red"
                                 Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                 HeightRequest="40"
                                 IsBorderErrorVisible="{Binding IsNotValid, Mode=TwoWay}" InputTransparent="{Binding ROnly}">
                        <local1:ExtendedEntry.Behaviors>
                            <behavior:EmptyEntryValidationBehaviour />
                        </local1:ExtendedEntry.Behaviors>
                    </local1:ExtendedEntry>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
        <local:MetaDataTemplateSelector x:Key="metaDataTemplateSelector"
            TextTemplate="{StaticResource textTemplate}"
            CheckboxTemplate="{StaticResource checkboxTemplate}"
            DatePickerTemplate="{StaticResource datepickerTemplate}"
            NumericTemplate="{StaticResource numericTemplate}"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="MetadataListView" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource metaDataTemplateSelector}"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
             HasUnevenRows="true"
             RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}"
             IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
             IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}"
             CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">

        </ListView>
        <Button Text="Save" Command="{Binding OnValidationCommand}"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: You really need to be able to summarize your questions. I read it diagonally and couldn't grasp what you were asking. Reformulate this wall of text to something less dense, or just reiterate what you were trying to ask.